# How to restrict user to select date between range of Years in Primefaces?

Tags: primefaces

I am struggling with primefaces calendar. I need that if today is July,28,2011 , I could be able to restrict the user to select dates in range of 1 year before July,28 and 3 years after July,28.

I looked at primefaces forum but could not found anything relevant. Please help..anyone!!!

Answer (score 2):

The PrimeFaces `<p:calendar>` has two attributes `mindate` and `maxdate` to restrict the selectable date range on the calendar. The value for these attributes can either be a java.lang.String or java.util.Date object.

Example:

```
<p:calendar mindate="07/27/2010" maxdate="07/28/2012" value="#{indexBean.date}" mode="inline" />
```

You can calculate the `mindate` and `maxdate` you want in your bean.

Answer (score 1):

The `<p:calendar>` has a `yearRange` attribute.  I think you want to set the value to `"c-1:c+3"` to indicate 1 year before and 3 years past the current year.  I'm getting this from the PrimeFaces 2.2 Guide.

Comment: The yearRange attribute sets the jQuery Datepicker [yearRange](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Datepicker#option-yearRange). The yearRange sets the range of years displayed in the year drop down. The year drop down only shows when `navigator="true"` on the `<p:calendar>`.  This would not work for Suman_Sohal's example (only wants dates selected 1 year before July 28, 2011) because it does not prevent the user from selecting a date between Jan 1 2010 and July 27 2010.